# iOS buttons fixed at the top

Tags: ios

I want to make something similar to the Facebook newsfeed. If you click on the image below:

[image]

There are three buttons near the top Status, Photo and Check In. When I scroll down the feed, the three buttons also scroll up and are not visible. But when I scroll back up, they buttons reappear. Is there an example of how to do this?? I have been looking for this for some time, thank you!

Comment: seems like you are right. If you post that as a answer I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add those buttons to the navigation bar so the position will be fixed ate the top
and for background go through this tutorial   https://github.com/scelis/ExampleNavBarBackground